# Linear endomorphisms of $k(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field and let $k(t)$ denote the field of rational variables in $t$. Is it possible to characterize all $k$-linear transformations from $k(t)$ to $k(t)$? Is $End_{k}(k(t)) \cong k(t)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $k$-algebra endomorphisms (i.e., $k$-linear maps which are also ring homomorphisms)?

Comment: @user254022: no, just $k$-linear transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most explicit description you can get is via partial fraction decompositions. Let $P$ denote the set of monic irreducible polynomials over $k$. Then every $f/g \in k(t)$ has a unique representation of the form
$$\frac{f}{g}=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{0,0,n} t^n +\sum_{p \in P}\sum_{r > 0} \frac{a_{p,r,0} + a_{p,r,1}t + \cdots a_{p,r,r\deg(p)-1}t^{r\deg(p)-1}}{p^{r}},$$
with only finitely many coefficients nonzero. So you get a $k$-basis of $k(t)$ as $$\{ t^n \mid n \ge 0 \} \cup \Big\{ \frac{t^i}{p^r} \mid p \in P, r > 0, 0 \le i < r \deg(p) \Big\}.$$
Now, as usual, a $k$-linear endomorphism of $k(t)$ can send each of these basis elements to an arbitrary element of $k(t)$.

In any case, certainly $\operatorname{End}_k(k(t))\ncong k(t)$, since $k(t)$ is a field while $\operatorname{End}_k(k(t))$ has zero-divisors (already for finite-dimensional vector-spaces, as long as the dimension is greater than $1$).

As for the follow up question on $\operatorname{End}_{k[t]}(k(t))$, let me first prove the following.

**Lemma** Let $R$ be an integral domain and $K$ its quotient field. Any $R$-linear homomorphism $f\colon K\to K$ is already $K$-linear, and hence of the form $f(x)=ax$ for some $a \in K$. In particular, $\operatorname{End}_R(K)=\operatorname{End}_K(K)\cong K$.

**Proof:** It suffices to show that $f$ is $K$-linear, the rest then follows easily. Let $a \in R$, $b \in R\setminus\{0\}$, and $x \in K$. We have to show $f(\frac{a}{b}x)=\frac{a}{b}f(x)$. By $R$-linearity of $f$, we have $b f(\frac{a}{b}x) = f(b\frac{a}{b}x) = f(ax)=af(x)$. Now divide by $b$, and we are done.

Applying the lemma to $R=k[t]$ gives $\operatorname{End}_{k[t]}(k(t)) = \operatorname{End}_{k(t)}(k(t)) \cong k(t)$.

Comment: of course, thanks; how about $End_{k[t]}(k(t))$?

Comment: If $R$ is a domain, and $K$ is it's quotient field, then a standard argument (via localization) shows that every $R$-homomorphism $f\colon K \to K$ is of the form $f(x)=ax$ with $a \in K$. In particular, $f$ is already $K$-linear. So $\operatorname{End}_{k[t]}(k(t)) = \operatorname{End}_{k(t)}(k(t)) \cong k(t)$.

Comment: The argument I have in mind usually appears when introducing Picard groups of Dedekind domains, to show that ideals are isomorphic iff they are related by a constant of the quotient field. Unfortunately, I don't have a reference handy, but it's very short: View $K$ as $R$-module, let $T=R\setminus \{0\}$, and let $T^{-1}K$ be the localization of the $R$-module $K$. Then $f$ extends to a $T^{-1}R=K$-module homomorphism $T^{-1}f\colon T^{-1}K\to T^{-1}K, \frac{x}{t} \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{t}$. However, $T^{-1}K=K$ from the def. of the localization of a module. (continued below)

Comment: Therefore $T^{-1}f$ is a $K$-linear endomorphism of $K$, and hence there exists $a \in K$ such that $T^{-1}f(x)=ax$ for all $x \in K$. But now observe that in fact $T^{-1}f(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in K$. So $f(x)=ax$ for all $x \in K$.

Comment: I have added a more direct proof of this to the answer.